# Mobile site shows rep gain on meta sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, mobile-web

Despite the fact that no reputation is gained on meta sites other than meta.SO , I still see +5 and +10 rep gains in the "reputation" section on the *mobile* meta user page.

Note that this does not actually add to my reputation, only that it mistakenly looks like it does.

Can anybody else confirm this?

Comment: the desktop version of sites does this in the "activity" dropdown on all pages by your name. I always thought it was odd.

Comment: @BenBrocka only on MSO, on the others I see votes, votes cast, revisions, and favorites.  I can confirm this on the mobile site though.

Comment: On Meta.UX I see +10 for answer upvotes in the dropdown as if I had actually gained rep. It doesn't show the reputation line but it shows the `+X rep Question Title` lines for recently up/downvoted items

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug, mobile had a special case of sections to show on the summary tab that didn't take into account the child meta case...it'll be fixed in the next build.

Comment: but I WANT to know about my precious meta reps! :P